# Azure Automations - Can we pass parameters from a powershell main runbook to a python child

Tags: azure, automation, azure-functions, power-automate, azure-runbook

I'm facing an issue for which i have not found the solution.
I trying to execute a python runbook from my parent which is in powershell.

The list of commands i tried in my powershell runbook :

- Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -ResourceGroupName "" -AutomationAccountName "" -Name "" -Parameters $params
- Start-AutomationRunbook -Name "" -Parameters $params
- Start-AzAutomationRunbook -ResourceGroupName "" -AutomationAccountName "" -Name "" - Parameters $params

Here is my variable params :

- $params = @{"args"="Hello"}

If anyone has the solution I'll be grateful ! I tried all day without success.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -Parameters option doesn't work for Python runbooks . You can use the -Parameters option of Start-AutomationRunbook from inside another runbook.

The workaround is to use the [internal Automation module Start-AutomationRunbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#internal-cmdlets) instead of the external Start-AzureRmAutomation module.

Create a new runbook named **Start-PythonRunbook** as follow :

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$runbook,
    [string]$args
    )
Start-AutomationRunbook -Name $runbook -Parameters $args
```

Now you can start this runbook using the **Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook** cmdlet :

```
Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -ResourceGroupName <RGName> 
    -AutomationAccountName <AAName> 
  -Name Start-PythonRunbook `
  -Parameters  @{ "runbook" = "<pythonrunbookname>"; "args" = "arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6" }
```

You can check this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5313) for more information.